# looping through all child elements(different types) using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a xml with following elements

```html
<Test>
<description>Sample</description>
<Action>Click</Action>
<Action>Submit</Action>
<Image>
  <Path> C:/...</Path>
</Image>
<Action>XYZ></Action>
<Image>
  <Path> C:/..</Path>
</Image>
</Test>
```

```
enter code here
```

I wanted to loop through all Actions and Images under TEST element using XSL and then display in HTML code like
action followed by image if there is any; if there is no Image then just display action then move to next action.

having difficulty in identifying Action & Image elements from the all other elements that are under TEST element. I have HTML code though.

Comment: Please add the expected result (as HTML code) to your question, as well as your current XSLT attempt.

Comment: I am new to XSL struggling with for each to loop through the elements under TEST element.

Comment: I got it - to loop through I used Test/* that gave me all elements under this and then I had to use name(.) to get the element name so that I can look at the elements that I am interested in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it - to loop through I used Test/* that gave me all elements under this and then I had to use name(.) to get the element name so that I can look at the elements that I am interested in it.